# Spring mongodb annotation for 2dsphere index for a geospatial field in java...?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mongo, spring-mongodb

```
@JsonSerialize
@Document(collection = "fence")
@CompoundIndexes({
        @CompoundIndex(name = "loc_groupId_idx", 
                       def = "{ 'loc': 2dsphere, 'groups.groupId': 1 }",      
                       unique = false) })
public class GeofenceMongoVO {

  public GeofenceMongoVO() {}

  @Id
  private String fenceId;

  @Field
  private Long customerId;

  @Field
  private String fenceName;

  @Field
  private Byte type;
```

This is how I tried to ensure a compound index on a geospatial field and a field of a child document(groupId). But this is not working unfortunately. Is there a way by which I can ensure 2dsphere index from java code via annotations?

Comment: You have a typo, that's why it does not work. Should be `"{ 'loc': '2dsphere', 'groups.groupId': 1 }"` with quotes `''` around the "2dsphere".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it can be done with annotations yet, but I found a blog post [here](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/02/spring-data-mongodb-geospatial-queries/) where they do it with an ensureIndex. Something like th

```
@Autowired
MongoTemplate template;

public void setupIndex()
{
    template.indexOps(Location.class).ensureIndex( new GeospatialIndex("position") );
}
```

Answer (score 7):

As of Spring Data MongoDB 1.10.10.RELEASE, you can annotate any field, whether it be at the document root or in a subdocument with:

```
@GeoSpatialIndexed(type = GeoSpatialIndexType.GEO_2DSPHERE)
private GeoJsonPoint myGeometry;
```

Comment: Can't be more accurate, should be updated as the good anwers !

Comment: Now you need to enable auto index creation in properties file too: data.mongodb.auto-index-creation: true